# How to display items in multiple rows

Tags: wpf, xaml, panel

I want to create a layout in XAML as follows[image]

A view model is used to populate the cells. The first two cells bind to two simple properties in the view model while the remaining cells show the items of a collection in the view model. Each row has four cells and the number of rows is decided by the number of items of the collection.
     How to define a panel to display the collection starting from cell 3 and span multiple rows in XAML?

Comment: can't you add the first two cells to the collection? this would perhaps simplify the solution.

Comment: Have you looked at WrapPanel?

Comment: In my view model, it has two string properties and a collection of user-defined objects. So they cannot be combined. I also considered the WrapPanel, but the items of the collection does not be shown from the first cell of a row. So if I use WrapPanel, it will overlap with the first 2 cells.

Comment: do you display a list of usercontrols?

Comment: No. I want to display a list of CLR objects in a grid starting in the middle of a row and span multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I get what you need using 2 uniformgrid:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="4"  VerticalAlignment="Top" >
   <Rectangle Fill="green" Width="50" Height="50" />
   <Rectangle Fill="green" Width="50" Height="50"/>
</UniformGrid>
<UniformGrid Columns="4"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FirstColumn="2">
   <Rectangle Fill="red"  Width="50" Height="50"/>
   <Rectangle Fill="red"  Width="50" Height="50"/>
   <Rectangle Fill="red"  Width="50" Height="50"/>
   <Rectangle Fill="red"  Width="50" Height="50"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

I don't know how your ViewModel is but I think it would be quite simple bind your property and your list to the uniform grid.